# How can I integrate a location search on my webpage with google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I currently have Google Maps integrated into my webpage. It is being used to tell the user where an event is (generally, it's a user submitted event). The previous programmer put it the functionality to center the map on a latitude and longitude, if you knew it. However, most people don't know the latitude and longitude of locations (sometimes they do but...), and the users want to be able to enter just a street address like you do when you go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com). How can I get it to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [Google Maps Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding).

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) and Google exposes public Geocoding services.

Here's a link to the [Google Geocoding Developer service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
Here's a link to [Yahoo's Geocoding API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html).

Read the docs.  You'll send the address and receive back the Latitude and Longitude.